# Which of the 3 analytics tracking codes will offer best performance (added specific details about my site)

Tags: performance, google-analytics

I could find three different tracking codes for google analytics - two from developer docs and one from the analytics interface itself. I am confused about which one to use for my website (details I have given at the end).

From developer docs (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs)

**Type 1**

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

**Type 2**: (Docs say, this code enables modern browsers to preload, but may degrade the performance in older ones. Should we care about those old browsers?)

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

**Type 3**: From the analytics interface

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-Y"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-Y');
</script>
```

**My Website Info:**

My website is mostly viewed on iPhones by US visitors. My pages are script heavy with lots of third-party scripts especially relating to google ad manager and other ad networks. If given a choice, I will give last priority to google-analytics even if it means I can miss few user sessions on the analytics. Hence, analytics should be non-blocking (loading and execution) at the best.

Comment: @moderator Sorry but I am not sure how this question could be opinion based? There are three different implementations of tracking codes from Google docs and analytics interface. I hoped this had an objective answer based on requirements... If this question can be improved, please let me know the way forward...

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in performance, ga and gtag have different syntax because they allow you to do different advanced configurations on the page (gtag is newer and more flexible).